# Ansible - Copy multiple files on remote host

Tags: ansible

I would like to copy few files on remote host , I used copy module as following but it copy all files under 'app' variable (dir) to 'backup_conf' variable (dir).
please advice here.

```
- name: backup configuration files
  copy:
   src: '{{ app }}'
   dest: '{{ backup_conf }}'
   remote_src: true
  with_items:
   - /bin/setenv.sh
   - /conf/server.xml
```

Comment: You are not referencing the items. According your example there should be something like `src: "{{ item }}"` and `dest: "{{ backup_conf }}/{{ item }}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I fixed my issue:

```yaml
- name: backup configuration files
  copy:
   src: "{{ item }}"
   dest: "{{ backup_conf }}"
   remote_src: true
  with_items:
   - /bin/setenv.sh
   - /conf/server.xml
```

Comment: Use `loop`. Simple `with_items` is deprecated.